# Simple graph diameter upper limit

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a simple **G** graph where $ |V(G)|\ge 2$ and  $ \delta(G) \ge\frac{|V(G)|-1}{2}$ prove that $ diamG \le 2$

Can somebody give me a tip on this one? I am having a hard time to find a theorem to work with or a way to start a proof by contradiction.Any clues or ideas on how to start?

Comment: Can you prove that any two vertices are connected by and edge or have a common neighbor (using pigeonhole)?

Comment: What is definition of $\delta(G)$?

Comment: $ \delta(G) $ is the lowest grade a vertex can have in G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u,v$ be two vertices.  We show that the distance $d(u,v)\leq 2$.  This proves that the diameter is at most $2$.

If $u=v$ or $u$ and $v$ are connected by an edge, we are done.  Suppose that $u$ and $v$ are not connected by an edge.  If there is some vertex $w$ that is a common neighbor of $u$ and $v$, then we are done.  Suppose that $w$ does not exist.  Then the neighbors of $u$ and $v$ are distinct.  Since there are at least $\frac{|V(G)|-1}{2}$ neighbors of each, this accounts for $|V(G)|-1$ vertices, none of which are $u$ or $v$.  Adding in $u$ and $v$ gives too many vertices, a contradiction.  Therefore, $w$ exists and $d(u,v)\leq 2$.